# Creating a chest with a specific spawn egg inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a parkour for my server and the prize would be a villager egg but when I use this command to refresh the chest for others it's just an egg that says: "spawn"

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~4 ~ {TileID:146,Time:0.9,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:383,Slot:1,Count:1}]}
```

How do I make this a villager egg?

Answer (score 2):

Your spawn egg isn't a villager egg if you don't set its damage value.  In your case try `Damage:120` in addition to the id, count, and slot.

Comment: I assume the id:383 is just for a spawn egg, and it needs the Damage:120 value to show that it needs to be defined as a villager egg?

Answer (score -1):

If you press F3 + H over a villager spawn egg it should say
"Spawn Villager 383:120" instead of having 383 in the area put 383:120

Answer (score -1):

Here's a command that can give you a Villager spawn egg `/give {player} minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"villager"}}`

If you are in a older version of minecraft then here's the command `/give {player} minecraft:spawn egg 1 120`

But to put that in a chest then is this /give {player} chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:spawn_egg,Count:1,tag:{EntityTag:{id:villager}}}]}}

if you want to summon the chest then is this /setblock ~ ~ ~1 chest 0 replace {Items:[{Slot:0,id:spawn_egg,Count:1,tag:{EntityTag:{id:villager}}}]}.